# Create slice from another slice but with a different type

Tags: go

Is there an easy and readable way to create a copy of a slice but with another type?
For example, I'm receiving a slice of int32 (`mySlice []int32`), but I need a copy of it and the copy should be int64: `copyOfMySlice []int64`.

### I neeed something like:

```
func f(s []int32) int32 {
    
    var newSlice = make([]int64, len(s))

    copy(newSlice, s) // how this can be done?

    // work with newSlice

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is to translate and copy each element, one by one. You can write a copy function using a function callback:

```
func CopySlice[S, T any](source []S, translate func(S) T) []T {
    ret := make([]T, 0, len(source))
    for _, x := range source {
        ret = append(ret, translate(x))
    }
    return ret
}
```

And use it:

```
intSlice:=CopySlice[uint32,int]([]uint32{1,2,3},func(in uint32) int {return int(in)})
```

Answer (score 2):

Go doesn't have standard functions like `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()` and others. You can write your own function for converting one slice to another:

```
func sliceInt64(arr []int32) []int64 {
    result := make([]int64, 0, len(arr))
    for _, num := range arr {
        result = append(result, int64(num))
    }

    return result
}
```

Also you can use package [lo package](https://github.com/samber/lo#map) that has `Map` function which manipulates a slice of one type and transforms it into a slice of another type:

```
import "github.com/samber/lo"

result := lo.Map([]int32{1, 2, 3, 4}, func(x int32, index int) int64 {
    return int64(x)
})
fmt.Println(result) // []int64{1, 2, 3, 4}
```